# Jquery or Javascript remove from combobox all option except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like you to help me with this please, I'd like to remove all options from a combobox except the one with value=3. I have this code but is not working.

```
<select id="Select1" name="Select1">
    <option selected value="1">Pink</option>
    <option value="2">Black</option>
    <option value="3">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Blue</option>
    <option value="5">White</option>
</select>


<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Remove option">

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var select=document.getElementById('Select1');

        for (i=0;i<select.length;  i++) {
           if (select.options[i].value!=document.getElementById('TextBox1')) {
             select.remove(i);
           }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's little bit unclear to us that what you're trying to do...to iterate over each select element or just only to options....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the following ways:

```
$("#Select1 option").not("[value='3']").remove();

$("#Select1 option:not([value='3'])").remove();

$("#Select1 option[value!='3']").remove();
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bh3L1oen/

Comment: However, OP is iterating over each select element, so I'll go with each() method...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal he's getting the select by its id, id should be unique therefore there should be just only 1 select

Comment: the mistake could be the getElementById or the loop on just 1 element.. who knows :) he's not specifying that he wants to iterate on a set of select elements..

Comment: This is working ! than you , I'd like to change the value for a textbox value, do, this is not working, what is wrong here please :  
 $("#Select1 option").not("[value='$('textBox1').val()']").remove();

Comment: @tonydeleon check for syntax errors in that statement. Shouldn't be hard

Answer (score 2):

This attribute selector will do it

```
$('#Select1 option[value!=3]').remove()
```

Reference: [Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ruuj8ctv/)**</kbd>

Comment: @BhojendraNepal OP is targeting an ID though, and states wants specific element

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `.value` when you're checking the text in the text box. You should be using:

```
document.getElementById('TextBox1').value
```

instead of just using:

```
document.getElementById('TextBox1')
```

Comment: Actually, this should be the best answer as OP has javascript code instead of jQuery.... but wait... what about `select.options[i]` that OP is using....

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('select').each(function(){
  if($('option',this).attr('value') != '3'){
    $('option',this).remove();
  }
});
```